# How to grant write privillage to folder for a windows group in powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

In my scenario, i have to read the windows groups of the machine. I just need to grant write permission to the folder for some of the windows groups.

I need to implement this in Powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use below script to get list of Windows groups of machine, i guess you need users in administrator group, below script will list members in administrator group.

```
$compname = hostname    
$computer = [ADSI]("WinNT://" + $compname + ",computer")
$Group = $computer.psbase.children.find("Administrators")
$Group.psbase.invoke("Members") | %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
```

and its output will be sonething like below

```
Administrator
Domain Admins
```

Once you get the required groups you can assign permission using below powershell cmdlet
in my scenario im setting write permissions to "C:\Data\Learning Products", i mean "Learning products" folder for "Domain Admins"

```
$Acl = Get-Acl "C:\Data\Learning Products"
$Ar = New-Object  system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("Domain Admins","Write","Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl "C:\Data\Learning Products" $Acl
```

Once the Permission is set you can verify it by running

```
Get-Acl "C:\Data\Learning Products" | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  } | ft -Wrap
```

Which wpuld indeed show that "domain admins" now have write access to the folder

P

```
osh (0310) >  Get-Acl "C:\Data\Learning Products" | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  } | ft -Wrap

   FileSystemRights   AccessControlType IdentityReference           IsInherited    InheritanceFlags    PropagationFlags
   ----------------   ----------------- -----------------           -----------    ----------------    ----------------
 Write, Synchronize               Allow GDNINDIA\Domain                   False                None                None
                                        Admins

        FullControl               Allow BUILTIN\Administrat                True                None                None
                                        ors
                                          ObjectInherit
        FullControl               Allow NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                True                None                None

        ReadAndExecute,           Allow BUILTIN\Users                      True     ContainerInherit,              None
        Synchronize                                                                    ObjectInherit

Modify, Synchronize               Allow NT AUTHORITY\Authen                True                None                None
                                        ticated Users
```